# How to display an image when aAsynch post back is happening

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have an Ajaxable application which has some UpdateProgress for each postBack events. everything is good and working great.

I want to display another Indicator in my SiteMapPath bar which shows a post back is happening no matter what.

For example when user clicks on a button an UpdateProgress display an Indicator Image in central part of application. I want to display another image ( for every postbacks not only for one) in top of application toolbar.

Currently I use a simple Flag out ther and I want to use an indicator instead of that flag when ever a postback happens

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you could do this in jquery alone by utilizing the ajaxSend and ajaxComplete events. Just bind a function to these events that will display your indicator and then hide the indicator.  Take a look at the [jquery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) for more info.

```
 $("#loading").bind("ajaxSend", function(){
   $(this).show();
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
   $(this).hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have more than one asp:UpdateProgress control which point the to the same AssociatedUpdatePanelID

Comment: The Flag update panel is on the master page and will upate with all update panels so that i can not associate an update Panel ID to it.

Comment: Well then if you just want a global one. if you you put the updatetemplate on a master page without a associated updatepanel id it will just go off with any async postback that goes on. so it will be what you want. no?

Comment: just saw we are from the same town :) samilik rafigh!